Read some pixels from oes texture precisely
For some reason I want to read some pixel (let say 400 bytes or 100 pixels) from OES texture precisely because I'am using the data as some protocal.
If I use traditional drawing triangle method to draw oes-texture to a 2dtexture, it may be interpolated because of the rasterization/sampling processing of gpu.
As far as I know, there is no way to copy buffer from oes texture.
So I want to know how to use shaders to precisely read these pixels, for example drawing 100 points so that every fragment shader instance can read one pixels from (0,0), (1,0) .. to (99,0).

Option one: use GL_NEAREST sampling filter with a traditional texture() lookup to avoid interpolation.
Option two: use texelFetch() to pull directly from an integer index.
